# Is it possible to have rectangular tabs on Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-lion, tabs

I'm on OSX 10.7, can I have rectangular tabs on Google Chrome?

Comment: What's a square tab?

Comment: @DanielBeck: I must assume *rectangular* is requested here (instead of the default, trapezoid shape).

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've edited the question. Oliver Salzburg understood well my zenglish ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If Oliver Salzburg is correct, and you want differently shaped tabs:

It's hardcoded in `(NSBezierPath*)bezierPathForRect:(NSRect)rect` of [chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/tabs/tab_view.mm](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/tabs/tab_view.mm).

You could try to play around with the constants used there, and compile Chrome/Chromium yourself:

```
// Constants for inset and control points for tab shape.
const CGFloat kInsetMultiplier = 2.0/3.0;
const CGFloat kControlPoint1Multiplier = 1.0/3.0;
const CGFloat kControlPoint2Multiplier = 3.0/8.0;
```

Comment: +1 I am amazed someone happens to just know this

Comment: @datatoo It's not *that* hard to search through source code :P

Comment: @slhck Shhhh. Don't spill my secrets!

Comment: Thank you Daniel Beck, I'll try to compile chrome and see if I can tweak those corners ;)

Comment: @dome Any progress?